# Calculating XY positions from path reverses when path turns

Tags: c++, math, coordinate-systems, polygons

**Scroll down to the edit to read part 2**

So I am working on a project where I need to create a polygon using given X and Y coordinates. The coordinates a given in logical order and create a path. Now I need to calculate all positions of a poligon, if the path width would be [w] (for example 20 meters). We all know lines have no width.

This image explains a bit what I want to do:

[image: Path]

The black dots are the positions of the path, their X and Y coordinates are known.
The width of the red lines is known, they are all [w] (for example 20 meters, the path cuts them in the center).

I do not know how to get the X,Y positions of all the purple dots. I need them so I can create the green polygon shape.

How can I calculate these positions in C++? Are there any functions which make it easier?

P.S: As you see the red lines are angeled at the half of the angle of two blue lines.

---

Edit:

I created a visualisation app in Visual Basic .NET and I got the formulas which I can port to C++. There is still one problem, please look at this image:
[image]

(app download link: http://gpb.googlecode.com/files/DRAWER2.zip )

The problem now is that when the path turns, it reverses the sides on which the points of the polygon get created. This makes an corrupted polygon (or well, it doesn't provide the wanted effect).

The code looks as following:

```
Dim MainImage As New DynamicBitmap

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim temp As New DynamicBitmap
    MainImage.CreateGrid(500, 500, 1, 1)
    temp.LoadBitmap("map.jpg")
    MainImage.DrawOnSurface(temp.Bitmap, temp.Rectangle, MainImage.Rectangle)
    MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, 250, 500, 250)
    MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 250, 0, 250, 500)
    PictureBox1.Image = MainImage.Bitmap
    PictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
Dim CPG(0) As Point
Dim CurrCount As Integer = 0
Dim Distance As Double = 30.0
Function CalculatePositions(ByVal PointStart As Point, ByVal PointMiddle As Point, ByVal PointEnd As Point) As Point()

    Dim DeltaX As Double
    Dim DeltaY As Double
    Dim AdderX As Double
    Dim AdderY As Double
    Dim Length As Double
    Dim CP(9) As Point
    CP(0) = PointMiddle
    CP(1) = PointStart
    CP(2) = PointEnd
    Dim RetP(1) As Point
    DeltaX = CP(1).X - CP(0).X
    DeltaY = CP(1).Y - CP(0).Y
    Length = Math.Sqrt(((DeltaX * DeltaX) + (DeltaY * DeltaY))) + 0.0000000001
    AdderX = (DeltaX / Length)
    AdderY = (DeltaY / Length)
    CP(3).X = (CP(0).X + (AdderX * Distance))
    CP(3).Y = (CP(0).Y + (AdderY * Distance))

    DeltaX = CP(2).X - CP(0).X
    DeltaY = CP(2).Y - CP(0).Y
    Length = Math.Sqrt(((DeltaX * DeltaX) + (DeltaY * DeltaY))) + 0.0000000001
    AdderX = (DeltaX / Length)
    AdderY = (DeltaY / Length)
    CP(4).X = (CP(0).X + (AdderX * Distance))
    CP(4).Y = (CP(0).Y + (AdderY * Distance))

    DeltaX = CP(3).X - CP(4).X
    DeltaY = CP(3).Y - CP(4).Y
    Length = Math.Sqrt(((DeltaX * DeltaX) + (DeltaY * DeltaY))) + 0.0000000001
    AdderX = (DeltaX / Length)
    AdderY = (DeltaY / Length)
    CP(8).X = (CP(4).X + (AdderX * Length / 2.0))
    CP(8).Y = (CP(4).Y + (AdderY * Length / 2.0))

    DeltaX = CP(8).X - CP(0).X
    DeltaY = CP(8).Y - CP(0).Y
    Length = Math.Sqrt(((DeltaX * DeltaX) + (DeltaY * DeltaY))) + 0.0000000001
    AdderX = (DeltaX / Length)
    AdderY = (DeltaY / Length)
    CP(7).X = (CP(0).X - (AdderX * Distance))
    CP(7).Y = (CP(0).Y - (AdderY * Distance))
    CP(9).X = (CP(0).X + (AdderX * Distance))
    CP(9).Y = (CP(0).Y + (AdderY * Distance))

    MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Red, New Point(CP(7).X - 3, CP(7).Y - 3), New Point(CP(7).X + 3, CP(7).Y + 3))
    MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Red, New Point(CP(7).X + 3, CP(7).Y - 3), New Point(CP(7).X - 3, CP(7).Y + 3))
    MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, New Point(CP(9).X - 3, CP(9).Y - 3), New Point(CP(9).X + 3, CP(9).Y + 3))
    MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, New Point(CP(9).X + 3, CP(9).Y - 3), New Point(CP(9).X - 3, CP(9).Y + 3))
    Return RetP
End Function

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    'MsgBox(DirectCast(e, MouseEventArgs).X.ToString() + ":" + DirectCast(e, MouseEventArgs).Y.ToString())

    ReDim Preserve CPG(CurrCount)
    'i -= 1
    CPG(CurrCount) = New Point(DirectCast(e, MouseEventArgs).X, DirectCast(e, MouseEventArgs).Y)
    MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, New Point(CPG(CurrCount).X - 3, CPG(CurrCount).Y - 3), New Point(CPG(CurrCount).X + 3, CPG(CurrCount).Y + 3))
    MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, New Point(CPG(CurrCount).X + 3, CPG(CurrCount).Y - 3), New Point(CPG(CurrCount).X - 3, CPG(CurrCount).Y + 3))
    CurrCount += 1
    If CurrCount = 1 Then

    Else
        If CurrCount = 2 Then
            Dim DeltaX As Double
            Dim DeltaY As Double
            Dim AdderX As Double
            Dim AdderY As Double
            Dim Length As Double
            DeltaX = CPG(CurrCount - 2).X - CPG(CurrCount - 1).X
            DeltaY = CPG(CurrCount - 2).Y - CPG(CurrCount - 1).Y
            Length = Math.Sqrt(((DeltaX * DeltaX) + (DeltaY * DeltaY))) + 0.0000000001
            AdderX = (DeltaX / Length)
            AdderY = (DeltaY / Length)
            Dim Temp(1) As Point
            Dim Angle01 As Double = Math.Atan2(CPG(CurrCount - 1).X - CPG(CurrCount - 2).X, CPG(CurrCount - 1).Y - CPG(CurrCount - 2).Y) * 180.0 / Math.PI
            Dim SinMin As Double
            Dim CosMin As Double
            SinMin = Math.Sin(((-Angle01) + 0.0) / 180.0 * Math.PI)
            CosMin = Math.Cos(((-Angle01) + 0.0) / 180.0 * Math.PI)
            Temp(0).X = CPG(CurrCount - 2).X + (CosMin * Distance) + AdderX * Distance
            Temp(0).Y = CPG(CurrCount - 2).Y + (SinMin * Distance) + AdderY * Distance
            Temp(1).X = CPG(CurrCount - 2).X - (CosMin * Distance) + AdderX * Distance
            Temp(1).Y = CPG(CurrCount - 2).Y - (SinMin * Distance) + AdderY * Distance
            MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Red, New Point(Temp(0).X - 3, Temp(0).Y - 3), New Point(Temp(0).X + 3, Temp(0).Y + 3))
            MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Red, New Point(Temp(0).X + 3, Temp(0).Y - 3), New Point(Temp(0).X - 3, Temp(0).Y + 3))
            MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, New Point(Temp(1).X - 3, Temp(1).Y - 3), New Point(Temp(1).X + 3, Temp(1).Y + 3))
            MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, New Point(Temp(1).X + 3, Temp(1).Y - 3), New Point(Temp(1).X - 3, Temp(1).Y + 3))
        End If
        MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, CPG(CurrCount - 2), CPG(CurrCount - 1))
        If CurrCount > 2 Then
            CalculatePositions(CPG(CurrCount - 3), CPG(CurrCount - 2), CPG(CurrCount - 1))
        End If
    End If

    PictureBox1.Image = MainImage.Bitmap
    PictureBox1.Refresh()

    'MsgBox(CP(i).ToString())
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim DeltaX As Double
    Dim DeltaY As Double
    Dim AdderX As Double
    Dim AdderY As Double
    Dim Length As Double
    DeltaX = CPG(CurrCount - 2).X - CPG(CurrCount - 1).X
    DeltaY = CPG(CurrCount - 2).Y - CPG(CurrCount - 1).Y
    Length = Math.Sqrt(((DeltaX * DeltaX) + (DeltaY * DeltaY))) + 0.0000000001
    AdderX = (DeltaX / Length)
    AdderY = (DeltaY / Length)
    Dim Temp(1) As Point
    Dim Angle01 As Double = Math.Atan2(CPG(CurrCount - 1).X - CPG(CurrCount - 2).X, CPG(CurrCount - 1).Y - CPG(CurrCount - 2).Y) * 180.0 / Math.PI
    Dim SinMin As Double
    Dim CosMin As Double
    SinMin = Math.Sin(((-Angle01) + 0.0) / 180.0 * Math.PI)
    CosMin = Math.Cos(((-Angle01) + 0.0) / 180.0 * Math.PI)
    Temp(0).X = CPG(CurrCount - 1).X + (CosMin * Distance) - AdderX * Distance
    Temp(0).Y = CPG(CurrCount - 1).Y + (SinMin * Distance) - AdderY * Distance
    Temp(1).X = CPG(CurrCount - 1).X - (CosMin * Distance) - AdderX * Distance
    Temp(1).Y = CPG(CurrCount - 1).Y - (SinMin * Distance) - AdderY * Distance
    MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Red, New Point(Temp(0).X - 3, Temp(0).Y - 3), New Point(Temp(0).X + 3, Temp(0).Y + 3))
    MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Red, New Point(Temp(0).X + 3, Temp(0).Y - 3), New Point(Temp(0).X - 3, Temp(0).Y + 3))
    MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, New Point(Temp(1).X - 3, Temp(1).Y - 3), New Point(Temp(1).X + 3, Temp(1).Y + 3))
    MainImage.Surface.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, New Point(Temp(1).X + 3, Temp(1).Y - 3), New Point(Temp(1).X - 3, Temp(1).Y + 3))

    PictureBox1.Image = MainImage.Bitmap
    PictureBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

How can I fix this issue? I want the red X-es on one side and the blue X-es on the other side, and I want it to not be dependable on how the path turns. How to accomplish this?

Comment: This is essentially a maths/geometry problem, and therefore off-topic.  One way to solve it is to find the equations of two adjacent green lines, and find their intersection.  Another way is to note that a red line bisects the angle formed by two adjacent blue lines.  Again, all of this can be solved with some straightforward maths.

Comment: Do you know how to get the angle between 2 vectors? Using 3 black points you can create 2 vectors, get the angle between them and make a new vector to scale by the width to generate your purple points.

Comment: any working examples? :P

Comment: I'm sure you can come up with working examples yourself if you can understand the concepts behind the code.

Comment: @Blender, look at my edit, now I have one final issue which I need to fix, I managed to do the calculations myself somehow, ;o

Comment: Your main issue is that you have not properly described the problem. How, exactly, is the path 20 width- primarily concerning the issue of the turning points. See "skinning" to see what I mean. It is easy to compute the points of the polygon for each individual section, but less easy to describe how each section fits together to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You an detect which side of a line a point is on.

```
position = Math.Sign( (Bx-Ax)*(Y-Ay) - (By-Ay)*(X-Ax) )
```

where `(Ax,Ay)` is the starting point, and `(Bx,By)` is the ending point of the line. `(X,Y)` is the point you want to check.

If the `position` is positive, it is on the left side, negative on the right (`0` on the line).

With this you swap the pink dots if they are on the wrong side of the path.

Answer (score 1):

First, gain the position of the purple points for the first and last segments (this is pretty trivial).

Then, for each of the blue lines, create two green lines which are parallel to it but appropriately spaced away from it. For the last and first blue line, you will have to explicitly terminate these lines at the points. This is easiest done by creating a blue line, of the appropriate length, at, say, 0,0, generating the two green lines, and then transforming them into position. It will also allow you to keep easier track of which line is which.

Then, simply compute the intersection of the green line on each side with the green line from the next segment along.

Here's my rather crappy paintathon.[image: Awful, I know. It's hand-drawn. In Paint.]

As you can see, the position of the purple points is easy to arrive at.